# as assembly, movw %ax, %bp doesn't work

Tags: linux, assembly, boot

I have a piece a assembly code(in at&t syntax) as below:

```
1  .globl start
2  start:
3  movw    %cs, %ax
4  movw    %ax, %ds
5  movw    %ax, %es
6 
7  movw    $boot_msg, %ax
8  movw    %ax, %bp
9  movw    $16, %cx
10 movb    $0x13, %ah
11 movb    $0x01, %al
12 movw    $0x000c, %bx
13 movb    $0, %dl
14 int     $0x10
15 
16 spin:
17 jmp     spin
18 
19 boot_msg:
20         .string "Hello, OS world!"
21 
22 .org (start + 510), 0
23 .word 0xaa55
```

however, after execution of line 8: movw %ax, %bp, the %bp register remain zero while %ax is some value non-zero. Why this instruction doesn't work?

Comment: I do not see an error, but why not use "movw $boot_msg, %bp"?

Comment: How are you verifying that the instruction did not have the intended effect?

Comment: @Michael I step into the code.

Answer (score 0):

I found two problems in your code:

1) BP should contain the string addr, the offset in "ES : OFFSET". But you use:

movw $boot_msg, %ax

mov %ax, %bp

Here, you read out the first 2 bytes 'H' & 'e' to BP, NOT the string addr!

You can use one instruction:

lea $boot_msg, %bp

2) DH should contain the 'ROW' vaule, but you didn't specify.

If you fix these two problems, the code should work fine.

Comment: Actually, `movw $boot_msg, %ax` _does_ get the address of `boot_msg` (note the `$` sign). `lea $boot_msg, %bp` is not a valid instruction (`lea boot_msg, %bp` would be valid, though).

Comment: Sorry, I am more familiar with intel syntax, not AT&T.

Comment: Indeed, I step into the code, and at line 8, the code being executed is not: movw    %ax, %bp. But later, I add the directive .code16 after label start, the problem is gone, don't know why?

Comment: Because the assembler use '.code32' by default. At lease the 32-bit GNU gas is so.